# Place multiple related records into single table with extra fields INTO SPECIFIC FIELDS

Tags: sql-server

I am using code supplied below by J.D.
I added a WHERE clause to limit my search to specific values in the STATUS field.
But when I get the results it displays them as first come first serve.
I am trying to figure out how to get them to fall into SPECIFIC fields based on those values

Any thoughts?

[image]

```
WITH _Table2Sorted AS -- Sorts the STATUS column by value ascending with SortId "buckets" to 
later be transposed on with a pivot
(
    SELECT
        BOVA,
        [STATUS],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BOVA ORDER BY [STATUS]) AS SortId
    FROM BOVA_STATUS
    WHERE STATUS=101 OR STATUS=102 OR STATUS=105 OR STATUS=106 
),
_Table2Pivoted AS -- Pivots the values of the STATUS column into each respective ordered 
Status# column, for each BOVA
(
    SELECT 
         PT.BOVA,
        MAX(PT.[1]) AS FedEndangered,  -- status 101
        MAX(PT.[2]) AS FedThreatened,  -- status 102
        MAX(PT.[3]) AS FedProposed,  -- status 105
        MAX(PT.[4]) AS FedCanidate,  -- status 106
    FROM _Table2Sorted
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX([STATUS]) FOR SortId IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])
    ) AS PT
    GROUP BY PT.BOVA -- Grouping needed to collapse all the pivoted rows into a single row per BOVA
)

-- Final results joined back to Table1 to get additional meta-data (PHYLUM, CLASS, etc)
     SELECT
    T2.BOVA,
    T2.[FedEndangered],
    T2.[FedThreatened],
    T2.[FedProposed],
    T2.[FedCanidate],
    T1.PHYLUM,
    T1.CLASS
FROM _Table2Pivoted AS T2
LEFT JOIN BOVA_TAXONOMY AS T1
    ON T2.BOVA = T1.BOVA
```

Comment: Just saw your new post here. In general this probably could've been an update to your original post to clarify, but this is ok too. So again, if you could please list the specific values of the `STATUS` column you care about and the order you want them displayed in the columns, and I'll modify my query accordingly.

Comment: They are specified above in the WHERE Clause and commented in the _Table2Pivoted Section.  I think that is what you are referring too???

Comment: Does what I posted not make sense?  I specified the specifc values in the code example above... they are in the WHERE statement.   WHERE STATUS=101 OR STATUS=102 OR STATUS=105 OR STATUS=106 ... They would be in the same order as the where clause.... Or am I missing something?????

Comment: Its not so much the order of columns but making sure that all 101's gets in the FedEndandered FIeld and all 102's get in the FedThreatened field and so forth

Comment: JD did I say or do something wrong?

Comment: No I just haven't had a chance to revisit your question, sorry. If I get a chance I will post an updated answer.

Comment: J.D. ok thanks .... this is really helping me learn by example... anything you can help with is truly appreciated.

Comment: J.D. Any thoughts on this?  Juts not sure how to make sure all the same like codes and be forced into a particular field.

Comment: Does anyone else have a thought on this?  Trying to modify the above to put specific values into specific columns...